# Get boolean value from checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I overtook a project from another dev'er.

The code allows me to get data from the form's text inputs, but not from the checkbox inputs.

The original developer wrote these functions (amongst others):

```
protected function getObjectString($key,$html=false,$escape=false) 
    {
        $string = isset($this->classData[$key]) ? $this->classData[$key]."" : ""; 
        if($html == true) $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
        if($escape == true) $string = addslashes($string);
        return $string;
    }
```

and

```
protected function getObjectBool($key,$toString=false,$trueVal="yes",$falseVal="no")
    {
        $bool = intval(isset($this->classData[$key]) ? $this->classData[$key] : 0);
        //$bool = intval(isset($this->classData[$key]) ? 1 : 0);
        if($toString == true)
        {
            if($bool > 0) return $trueVal;
            else return $falseVal;
        }
        return $bool > 0;
    }
```

When I use

```
getObjectString("Email",false,false);
```

I get the value of form element

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 formlabel">E-mail</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" value=""></div>
</div>
```

But when I use

```
getObjectBool("EmailMandatory",false,"yes","no");
```

I should get the value (checked=1, unchecked=0) from

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 formlabel">Mandatory</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <label style="font-weight: normal;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="EmailMandatory" value="1" checked>
            Use of mail address is mandatory
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the value (from getObjectBool) is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Addition, as requested by Professor Abronsius:

```
abstract class common_library_dbbase
{
    /** CLASS PROPERTIES **/
    protected $classData = array();

    /** CONSTRUCTOR **/
    function __construct($data,$tableName,$primaryIDName,$accountTable=false,$cacheEnabled = true)
    {
        
        // Set member data
        $this->tableName = $tableName;
        $this->primaryIDName = $primaryIDName;
        $this->cacheEnabled = $cacheEnabled;
        $this->accountTable = $accountTable;
        
        // Is same class        
        if(is_object($data) && get_class($this) == get_class($data))
        {
            $this->classData = $data->toArray;
        }
        
        // Is array data
        else if(is_array($data)) 
        {
            $this->classData = $data;   
        } 
        
        // Is number, load from db
        else if(intval($data) > 0) 
        {
            $this->classData = $this->loadByID($data);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$this->classData`? A checkbox, if unchecked, will not appear in the POST array so is that significant?

Comment: classData is a protected array in the php class dbbase.
I will add the entire class to my question.
Edit: obviously I cannot add the entire class. I will try to find out the most significant part.

Comment: I rather suspect that if you add all the class that might be too much - but the contents of that protected array might be useful

Comment: I added some of the class, hope that illuminates the subject a bit :)

Comment: As the method relies upon `$this->classData[$key]` it is more important to know what that array contains at the point when the method tries to use `$this->classData[$key]`

Comment: I am not sure how I could elaborate that ... Can you help me with that?

Comment: do a `var_dump($this->classData)` or `printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($this->classData,true) )` so show the contents

Comment: I could try, but I can't see the output right away, it is being parsed through a class. So it is not that easy ...

Answer (score 0):

When you pass false as second parameter the function returns a boolean, not an integer. You could do

```
getObjectBool("EmailMandatory",false,"yes","no") ? 1 : 0
```

Or

```
getObjectBool("EmailMandatory",true,1,0)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. Although I now get a value back, the value is always "no", regardless the state of the checkbox.

Comment: Ok, so the problem isn't within that function but in the way your object is initialized, you have to analyze the code deeper. Are you using a well known framework?

Comment: I overtook the system from another Dev'er. It's not an actual framework, but a very well-organized MVC.
I found a method that I am not proud of, but for the time being will it be ok. By using if (intval(IN::PostBool("EmailMandatory"))===1) I can fetch the current state of the checkbox, however, it does not solve the problem why getObjectBool does not work. PostBool is defined in class IN: public static function PostBool($name)
 {
  if(!self::hasPost($name)) return false;
  return in_array($_POST[$name],array(1,true,"on","true","1"));
 }

Comment: IN:PostBool reads the $_POST array directly (although you didn't post the hasPost method). getObjectBool expects to find the value within the classData member, but it can be initialized in different ways, you have to find where the object is instanced to understand how it works. You may throw an exception in the constructor to get a stack trace to help you find where to look at.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply :)
I added $MailMandatory=0;
  if (intval(IN::PostBool("EmailMandatory"))===1)
        {
            $MailMandatory=1;
        }
        $PhoneMandatory=0;
        if (intval(IN::PostBool("PhoneMandatory"))===1)
        {
            $PhoneMandatory=1;
        }
and that worked :) Now I can use an if-statement on these two integers.